# What are the names of the GUI components of a video player?

Tags: video-playback

I was looking at a video player and I didn't knew that the name of the seekbar is "seekbar". Is there any documentation for describing the components of a video player in general? (menu bar, seek bar, play/pause button etc)

Comment: *"I didn't know that the name of the seekbar is "seekbar"."* -- I wouldn't say this is necessarily uncommon, but I don't believe this is standardized in the way implied. That is, a certain media player could easily call this a e.g. "video progress control bar". In short, it seems unlikely that any real documentation exists about what a media player's control components are called outside the media player's own documentation.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really any standardization outside of really whatever you call it. You can probably find whatever your program calls it by looking through its documentation.